# ContentPresenter and Datatemplates with dependency properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

The main application window, minus a ton of code that is not relevant.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type presenters:DashboardViewModel}">
        <views:DashboardView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type presenters:SecondViewModel}">
        <views:SecondView />
    </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding WindowPresenter}"/>
</Window>
```

The view model that is bound to Window

```
public class RootViewModel {
    // IRL this implements notifypropchanged
    public IPresenter WindowPresenter {get; set;}
    public void ShowDashboard(){ this.WindowPresenter = new DashBoardViewModel(); }
    public void ShowSecond(){ this.WindowPresenter = new SecondViewModel(); }
}
```

`DashboardView` and `SecondView` are user controls with many dependency properties that are bound to properties in their resepective view models.

```
// example of a common dependency property I have 
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorPaletteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ColorPalette", typeof(ColorPalette), typeof(SurfaceMapControl), new PropertyMetadata(ColorPalette.Rainbow, new PropertyChangedCallback(SurfaceMapControl.ColorPalettePropertyChanged)));
private static void ColorPalettePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) { ((SurfaceMapControl)d).OnColorRangeChanged(); }
private void OnColorRangeChanged() { 
    // code that uses this.SomeOtherDependencyProperty
    // throws null ref exception
}
```

When calling `ShowDashboard()`, the content presenter shows the correct user control and all properties bind correctly.
On the call to `ShowSecond()`, the content presenter shows the correct user control and all properties bind correctly.

Occasionally when switching between the two views, I get null ref exceptions in a dependency property on one of the user controls since some of my properties look at other dependency properties. This leads me to believe that the viewmodel is being garbage collected before the view, and the change in viewmodel triggers the usercontrols dependency property, which in turn throws an exception because the viewmodel no longer exists.

Can I prevent the dependency properties from triggering when the viewmodel is disposed?

Or is it necessary to have null datacontext checks in every dependency property?

Is there something I should include here to look at the lifecycle of the usercontrols to prevent this altogether?

Comment: Null reference coming at what place? Property change event of DP?

Comment: As stated in the above code `this.SomeOtherDependencyProperty` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF, when binding, typically uses weak references for all of it's binding operations to prevent memory leaks from occurring.

As such, it's possible that your `ViewModel` can be cleaned up and gone at some point, while the control still is "alive", as the GC on the ViewModel can happen before the view is actually switched out.

The simplest solution is typically to just handle these change notifications with null checks, and skip the appropriate portions of the code.  This also can be useful, depending on how you setup things, at initialization/creation as well.